# MySQL/PHP Selecting Lat Long Between Range

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, range, distance

I hope, that my English is good enough to explain my problem.

I would like to create a circular search. The user enters a certain radius and receives all entries that affect this radius. For this I have specified in my database the Latitude and Longitude. Now, however, I do not know how to load the correct entries within my MySQL Query and these should also be sorted by distance.

On The Internet I found this code, which I don't understand. But maybe you can help me change it to what I need (I´m quite a beginner in MySQL and PHP).

The parameters from the users actual position is given to the script's function as `$user_lat` and `$user_long`.

Here is some code that I found online, but I don't know how to apply this to my situation:

```
SELECT F.*,K.ort,
((ACOS(SIN(K2.lat * PI() /180) * SIN(K.lat * PI() /180) + COS(K2.lat * PI() /180) * COS(K.lat * PI() /180) * COS((K2.lon - K.lon) * PI() /180)) *180 / PI()) *60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344) AS distance
FROM geodb_firmen AS F
JOIN geodb_koordinaten AS K ON K.plz=F.plz
LEFT JOIN geodb_koordinaten AS K2 ON K2.plz='$plz'
HAVING distance <= $dist
ORDER BY distance
```

Table structure:

```
+---+-------------+--------------+
| # |    Name     |     Type     |
+---+-------------+--------------+
| 1 | id          | int(11)      |
| 2 | user_id     | int(11)      |
| 3 | lati        | varchar(100) |
| 4 | longi       | varchar(100) |
| 5 | signup_date | timestamp    |
+---+-------------+--------------+
```

[A picture representation of the table structure can also be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgXcq.png)